# How to map the icons from the CSS file?

Tags: css, fonts, icons

I downloaded a free css theme and this theme uses css file and font files for icons and unfortunately the theme has no documentation. How can I visually export them to an html file instead of looking at the CSS file line by line?

```
https://yadi.sk/d/K1fgjd61wWCy8Q
https://yadi.sk/d/j3tjDtwa3Gucng
https://yadi.sk/d/QCi26iPmPE5QIA
https://yadi.sk/d/POI-p5eOsmQArQ
https://yadi.sk/d/tKJY9lGomWsqmg
```

It was obviously created through icomoon, but I want to see visually which icons are there.

Comment: Can you provide us more details?Which fonts they are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to clarify, you wanted to have a preview of the icons, right? That's why you're asking to convert it to HTML to easily view in the browser. If so, I hope this would do:

With the use of your .SVG file (https://yadi.sk/d/tKJY9lGomWsqmg), you can upload this to [https://icomoon.io/](https://icomoon.io/app). There, you can have a preview of the available icons with their corresponding names.

IcoMoon App has a feature of converting .SVG to icons. And with that, it also offers to have a preview of the icons with their names.

I tried opening the .SVG on itself, but (I'm not an expert here) I didn't get to have a preview of the icons.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for this practical suggestion. I hadn't thought of it.